# div inline-block usage and dynamic width depending on the number of divs

Tags: html, css

Basically, I need to display divs horizontally and set their widths automatically.

**test.html**

```
<div class="mypanel">
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**test.css**

```
.mypanel .col {
    display: inline;
    width: 33%;
}
```

If there are 3 columns so this is okay so I can set the width 33%. What if the number of columns (divs) is dynamic?

It may be set by javascript but I want to know if there is any other best practices?

Comment: Setting the width of an inline element won't do much.

Comment: will there be only ' div class="col"' be present inside the mypanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS Tables. They are [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) and [dead easy to work with](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

```css
.mypanel {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.mypanel .col {
  display:table-cell;
}

/* Small screens */
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .mypanel, .mypanel .col {
      display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mypanel">
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

For modern browsers you could use `flex-box` which supports a whole load of awesome properties. See: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.mypanel {
  display:flex;
}
.mypanel .col {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/* Small screens */
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .mypanel {
     display:block;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="mypanel">
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works as expected but how can we make it responsible? I mean when screen size gets smaller, cols should be listed vertically with full width. Is it possible achieve this with only css?